# How to remove multiple IIS bindings in PowerShell fast?

Tags: powershell, iis, iis-10, web-administration, hostheaders

In a process of version upgrade, our current solution takes all bindings (except for two dummy urls) from one site and setting them on another site.

I'm currently removing the bindings through PowerShell but it is super slow. I've looked on about every thread in SO and almost every solution uses "Remove-WebBinding".

This is my current code:

```
Get-Website -Name $siteName | Get-WebBinding  | Where-Object { $_.HostHeader -notlike '*dummy*' } | Remove-WebBinding;
```

I have 272 (-2 dummy) bindings to remove and it takes more about 3 minutes.

Any ideas how to do it faster?

BTW: Adding all of those bindings one by one is super-slow too, but I guess if I'll find an answer here a similar solution would do for adding as well.

Comment: This doesn't look right `Where-Object { $_.HostHeader -notlike '*dummy*' | Remove-WebBinding }` - is it a typo?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen -Yeah sorry I'll fix it in edit

Comment: It is doomed to be slow when using WebAdministration cmdlets, as each call creates the relevant underlying objects over and over again. Switch to IISAadministration cmdlets and use a single `ServerManager` object. That's a lot faster. https://blogs.iis.net/bariscaglar/iisadministration-powershell-cmdlets-new-feature-in-windows-10-server-2016

Comment: @LexLi That's the solution, thanks! My sctipt runs for 4 seconds now instead of 4 minutes (and it's a development environment which is a fracture of the size of the prod environment). Would you write a full answer that I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from the comment and expand it a little bit.

### Cause of Slowness

WebAdministration cmdlets were designed a long while ago, which has many disadvantages.

The slowness you observed can be explained as by design. Though it is not open sourced, we can guess that each call of `Remove-WebBinding` creates the relevant underlying objects (like `ServerManager`) and then commits change to IIS configuration file. Thus, the more bindings to remove, the longer it takes (and the more resources consumed).

### Solution

For all in-support IIS releases today (8+), you should use [IISAdministration cmdlets](https://blogs.iis.net/bariscaglar/iisadministration-powershell-cmdlets-new-feature-in-windows-10-server-2016) instead. They are newly developed with both flexibility and performance in mind.

By using a single `ServerManager` object and committing changes only once, removing bindings can be a lot faster.

Comment: Thanks! that solved it. My sctipt runs for 4 seconds now instead of 4 minutes (and it's a development environment which is a fracture of the size of the prod environment).

Answer (score 0):

try to run below PowerShell script:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration  
Get-WebBinding -HostHeader 'dummy' | Remove-WebBinding -Confirm:$true
```

Comment: I can't use the Confirm flag because this script should run without human intervention (part of a deployment pipeline)

Comment: @IdanLevi you could remove that confirm flag